# How to reference projects in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Assume that I have this solution structure:

- ProjectA (Class library - .NET Standard 1.5)
- ProjectB (Class library - .NET Standard 1.5)
- ProjectConsole (Console Application - netcoreapp1.0)

Where **ProjectB** has reference to **ProjectA**, and **ProjectConsole** has reference to **ProjectB**

If in project.json I declare something like that:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ProjectA": "1.0.0-*",
    ...
  },
```

Then in ProjectConsole it's possible to do something like this:

```
var projectA = new Project.Class1();
```

This happen because ProjectB has a reference to ProjectA.

But I don't want this, the question is, there is a way to prevent that?

Comment: Is projectA a variable or a class?

Comment: What are you talking about when you say "This happen because ProjectB has a reference to ProjectA."

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to prevent. Do you not want **ProjectConsole** to have access to **ProjectB**?

Comment: @AsifShiraz projectA is the nameSpace.

Comment: @NateBarbettini  I Try to prevent projectConsole instance public classes of projectA, just the public classes of projectB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't prevent it.

If **ProjectConsole** depends on **ProjectB**, and **ProjectB** references **ProjectA**, then ProjectConsole will implicitly have access to ProjectA's public members.

If you really want to prevent this, you could make ProjectA's members `internal` and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. But this isn't considered a good pattern - if B relies on A, it should rely on **public** members of A, or they should be merged into a single library.